# Test Plan isnt getting saved in Jemeter, showing Uncaught exception in thread

Tags: java, jmeter

Every time i am trying to save my test plan i am getting this Uncaught exception in thread.I have reinstalled Jmeter but its showing the same.Currently i am using these version
Jmeter - version 5.4.1
Java - version 17

I am getting this error showing in console

2021-12-17 19:58:40,289 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FileDialoger
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.computeFileName(Save.java:201) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.doAction(Save.java:163) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.doActionNow(ActionRouter.java:124) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractAction.popupShouldSave(AbstractAction.java:76) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.doAction(Start.java:111) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:69) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716) ~[?:?]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) ~[?:?]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741) ~[?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]

can anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

You're using this ̶u̶g̶l̶y̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶b̶u̶g̶g̶y̶ fancy and beautiful [`Darcula` theme](https://github.com/weisJ/darklaf), switch it to something else, i.e. to `Windows` or `Metal` and the issue should go away.

[image]

If for some reason you want to see grey letters on dark grey background - consider amending [line 112 of your jmeter startup script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.2/bin/jmeter.bat#L112) to look like

Or just downgrade to [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) which doesn't have these restrictions, [JMeter 5.4 version](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities) runs just fine on it.

```
set JAVA9_OPTS=--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now. changing the theme really works

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. I would never have thought of that solution.
Any idea why pasting doesn't work? It just makes a popping noise when I try to paste into the fields